# Is it possible to drop+create a schema throug Dapper?

Tags: c#, mysql, dapper

I would like to drop and create a database in MySQL through Dapper like this:

```
public class GenericSqlExecutionRepository
{
    private IDbConnection _db;

    public void RecreateDb()
    {
        _db.Execute("DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `my_db`;");
        _db.Execute("CREATE DATABASE `my_db`;");
    }
}
```

Drop database works just fine, but whe trying to execute the create database:

> "Unknown database 'my_db'"
>
> at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
>   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.ReadOk(Boolean read)
>   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.SetDatabase(String dbName)
>   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.SetDatabase(String dbName)
>   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.ChangeDatabase(String databaseName)
>   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
>   at Dapper.SqlMapper.ExecuteCommand(IDbConnection cnn, CommandDefinition& command, Action'2 paramReader)
>   at Dapper.SqlMapper.ExecuteImpl(IDbConnection cnn, CommandDefinition& command)
>   at Dapper.SqlMapper.Execute(IDbConnection cnn, String sql, Object param, IDbTransaction transaction, Nullable'1 commandTimeout, Nullable'1 commandType)

Of course my `IDbConnection` is tied to a single database (specified in the connection string). So: is it possible to bypass this problem and do the drop+create through Dapper?

---

**ADDITIONAL INFOS**

The var `_db` is generated like so:

```
public static MySqlConnection GetConnection(string connectionStringId)
{
    var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionStringId].ConnectionString;
    var connection = new MySqlConnection();
    connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;

    return connection;
}
```

This is the connection string in `App.config`:

```
<add name="myDbId" connectionString="Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=my_db;User=yyyyyyy;Password=zzzzzzz;Convert Zero Datetime=True;Compress=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like by simply removing `Database=my_db;`from the connection string, Dapper is OK with that:

```
<add name="myDbId" connectionString="Server=localhost;Port=3306;User=yyyyyyy;Password=zzzzzzz;Convert Zero Datetime=True;Compress=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Now both queries work.

Comment: That's was error is also suggesting it was failing at an attempt to use Invalid connection object, since underlying database has been dropped